# Change the URL of an particular page, using .htacces

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I need to change just an part of this URL

```
page.com/OLD?q=text+phrase
```

WITH THIS

```
page.com/NEW?q=text+phrase
```

Please note: this URL is an search result, in this case, the full url is formated from this parts:

- `page/` - the domain
- `/OLD` - this part (route) need to be changed
- `?q=` - is the query string
- `text+phrase` - this is the text writen in the search box by some user, so on click "enter" this text will be added at the end of the URL and the user will be redirected to the "search results page"

I need this redirect just for the external url (indexed by google) becouse i have 130.000 url indexed (mysite/old?q=...)

This is my actual code (this OLD - to - NEW - is NOT added in this code, becouse all my intent to get the correct code, have faill)

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php[^/] /$1? [L,R=301,NC,NE]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php(?:/(.*))?$ /$1$2? [L,R=301,NC,NE]

    RewriteRule ^/?filme-online/(.*)$ /online-filme/$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^/?filme-online(.*)$ /online-filme$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^/?seriale-online/(.*)$ /online-seriale/$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^/?seriale-online(.*)$ /online-seriale$1 [L,R=301]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L] 

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You should instead add the tries you made for the required task.

Comment: Well , I ve tray to add this new rule - RewriteRule ^/?old(.*)$ /new$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're adding the rules in an `htaccess` file, the following should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q= [NC]
RewriteRule ^busqueda\b /busquedaS [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: The result for the code above is - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS - this is the real page - https://www.google.es/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=site:pepecine.com%2Fbusqueda - and I will change the term "busqueda" for "busquedaS" with "s" at the end -

Comment: Of corse, right now, I have deleted the changes in the .htacces, and all results from google will go to 404